# Why GetimageSize function in php is not working for iphone portrait images

Tags: php, image

GetimageSize function of php to get image height,width and mime type of uploading images is not working for iphone portrait images.It is giving the images height into width parameters and vise versa.But it is working fine for landscape images.

Comment: You may have to check for the "Orientation" field in the EXIF data. Try using `jhead -v someImage.jpg | grep -i orientation` on an image - just to check if it is that.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php
$size = getimagesize($filename);
$fp = fopen($filename, "rb");
if ($size && $fp) {
    header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
} else {
    // error
}
?>
```

Comment: please add some description, so people will know whats mean that code..